# How to populate values based on a search textbox in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I need to show my grid based on the value entered in a textbox by the user.

In my html, i have given a grid

```
<table id="grid"></table>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g27gL/7/) on this.

Currently it is showing null value in my grid. I have made something wrong in my code. Can some one suggest me what needs to be done?

Thank you,

Comment: Why are you splitting the search text ??

Comment: @pawal: My code is not entering into $.each(s, function()). That is why i am trying by splitting the search text. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What is **.indexColumn** ? Does it have random value? Your have appended all the ID's into it. What is the user supposed to enter in the search box?

Comment: @shaunakde: i have populated the values what are all comes in emp name and populated in indexcolumn td as hidden for now. The user was suppose to enter only the emp name in that searchbox.

Comment: Your code works on reading **.indexcolumn** `$("#grid tr:visible .indexColumn:not(:contains('"+ s + "'))")` that contains ID of employee. I'l post correct solution in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/g27gL/10/)**.

---

Firstly, the *.indexcolumn* class was getting wrong values.

Change :

```
var t = $('#grid td:nth-child(2)').text().toLowerCase();
```

to

```
var t = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').text().toLowerCase();
```

---

Second, you have to search based on employee name nd not *.indexcolumn*, which contains ID.

Change:

```
$("#grid tr:visible .indexColumn:not(:contains('"+ this + "'))").parent().hide();
```

to

```
$("#grid tr:visible td[aria-describedby='grid_emp_name']:not(:contains('"+ s + "'))").parent().hide();
```

---

Third, I removed the logic of splitting the entered value, `contains()` works fine.